# Regular expression restrict the length number of stars(*) and numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying regular expression where i need to restrict  number of stars(*) and Numeric value i did like this to restrict Number of stars * `/([*]*\*[^*]*){9}/` which stars(*)will restrict up to 9 now with same i need to restrict Numeric also upto 9 please help me for the same.

Comment: Use `/(?:\d\D*){9}/`. I think you should write the `*` regex like `/(?:[*][^*]*){9}/`.

Comment: Hi  Wiktor i can restrict numeric upto 9 in the same expression i need to restrict Stars (*)  max 9

Comment: Please provide test cases (valid and invalid input). Also, please check [`^(?=(?:[^*]*[*]){9})(?=(?:\D*\d){9})`](https://regex101.com/r/hY4sY9/3).

Comment: Ex :: A. 12345****6789***** (Valid)    B. 1234534****6789***** (Invalid) C.12345*********6789***** (Invalid)

Comment: Max length of Stars should be 9 and Max length of Numeric should be 9 that's a requirement. please help for the same

Comment: Hi Wiktor:: Test Case will get failed A. ****12(Valid) B.****6766(Valid) C. 773***666**(Valid) for above expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=(?:[^*]*[*]){9})(?=(?:\D*\d){9})/
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `(?=(?:[^*]*[*]){9})` - requires the string to have at least 9 `*` symbols at any locations
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){9})` -  requires the string to have at least 9 digits at any locations

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hY4sY9/4)

The principles the regex is built on:

- Lookarounds anchored at the start (with `^`) check for their subpatterns presence just once
- They do not consume characters, so each of the lookaheads checks the string from its beginning
- The opposite subpatterns are used: `[^*]` to check for any character but `*` and `\D` checks for a non-digit character between one another (that is, `(?:[^*]*[*]){9}` matches 9 sequences of zero or more characters other than `*` followed with one `*`).

To only match a string that contains **up to**  9 digits and stars, you need to extend the lookaheads:

```
/^(?=(?:[^*]*[*]){1,9}[^*]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){1,9}\D*$)/
```

The negated character classes should be added at the end of each lookahead and `$` should be used in order to make sure we checked the whole string up to its end. `{1,9}` will match 1 to 9 subpatterns the limiting quantifier is applied to.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iU7lU9/2)

```js
var ss = [ "12345****6789*****", "1234534****6789*****", "12345*********6789*****", "****12", "****6766", "773***666**"]; // Test strings
var rx = /^(?=(?:[^*]*[*]){1,9}[^*]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){1,9}\D*$)/;  // The regex 
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                       // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + rx.test(ss[s]) + "</b><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor:: Test Case will get failed A. ****12(Valid) B.****6766(Valid) C. 773***666**(Valid) for above expression

Comment: Should there be at least one `*` and digit? What is the minimum amount required? I updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. well Minimum Number of Stars * is 4 and Max Number of Stars(*) is 9.... .Minimum and Maximum Number of Numeric  is 9

Comment: Your above requirement goes against the examples you posted earlier. Please adjust the limiting quantifier (`{min,max}`) yourself, since you and only you know the exact requirements.